# How to reshuffle a shuffled list in Python

Tags: python, random, shuffle

I am performing shuffle operations on nested lists in Python 3. I wish to reshuffle previously shuffled lists indefinitely until the order of the nested lists meet a specific criteria. random.shuffle operates in place and calling random.shuffle() on a previously shuffled list does not reshuffle it. What is the best way to reshuffle a list indefinitely until it meets a condition. For example, I was trying something like this, but making a new list then shuffling it doesn't seem to work:

```
from random import shuffle

L1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10]]
shuffle(L1)
match = L1[0]

# reshuffle until [9,10] is the first item in the list
if match != [9,10]:
    L1 = list(L1)
    shuffle(L1)
print(L1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

> calling random.shuffle() on a previously shuffled list does not reshuffle it

This is incorrect. Observe:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> L1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10]]
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> shuffle(L1)
>>> print L1
[[3, 4], [9, 10], [5, 6], [7, 8], [1, 2]]
>>> shuffle(L1)
>>> print L1
[[9, 10], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 2], [7, 8]]
>>>
```

The following code should do what you want, although it will have a non-deterministic runtime.

```
from random import shuffle

L1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10]]
match = [9,10]
while L1[0]!=match:
    shuffle(L1)
print(L1)
```

Comment: Correct, this is why I am copying the list `L1 = list(L1)`

Comment: You don't need to copy the list. You can reshuffle the same list over and over--it will reshuffle. @Jarek is right though: I can't comprehend what task this could possibly accomplish. Are you sure that there isn't a better algorithm for what you are doing that does not involve shuffling?

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure? On my machine, running `shuffle(L1)` shuffles L1, but only once. Running `shuffle(L1)` again does not reshuffle the list L1. Thanks for the help. There could be a better algorithm, but I see no way to get around the reshuffle at this point.

Comment: I updated my answer with a clear demonstration that `shuffle()` will reshuffle. Indeed, think about it logically--how would `shuffle()` even *know* it had shuffled the list already?

Answer (score 2):

It really seems inefficient to keep shuffling until a certain element is in the front. Why not take that element out, shuffle the remainder, then prepend that element to the front?

Comment: My example is an over-simplification. I'm actually generating a score for each shuffled list and I need to shuffle until a score above a certain threshold is generated.

Comment: @dr.bunsen - Then iterate through the list until you find an acceptable score.

Comment: @Butttons840 Perhaps you could demonstrate what you are describing? I do iterate through the list to find acceptable scores. If a score is not acceptable, I need to reshuffle until an acceptable score is obtained.